# tag called "canny-edge-detector"

Tags: discussion

What is that?

Can someone toss in a description?

"The question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar."

Without adding some cruft, I was unable to post this question to the meta page.

Comment: ?? http://lmgtfy.com/?q=canny+edge+detector ??

Answer (score 1):

I've added a brief entry. Let me know if that's OK.